# sending message to client using Django Channels from Celery tasks.py

Tags: python, django, websocket, celery, django-channels

I'm trying to use channels(v2.1.7) in django to send messages from server to client. When i execute the celery task below, my message is not being fetched in consumers.py(so not being sent to client) and surprisingly no error occures.

I'm able to send message from consumers to client directly. But i couldn't manage to send from outside of consumers using async_to_sync().

(I tried to use async_to_sync method in standard django views.py and i had same problem)

*wololo/tasks.py*

```
@app.task(name='wololo.tasks.upgrade_building')
def upgrade_building(user_id):


    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'DjangoFirebaseProject.settings'

    from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    print(channel_layer, "wololo")

    async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)('chat', {
        'type': 'hello.message',
        'message': 'hadiInsss',
    })

    return True
```

*wololo/consumers.py*

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
import json
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)("chat", self.channel_name)
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)("chat", self.channel_name)

    def hello_message(self, event):
        print("U MUST SEE THAT MSG")
        # Send a message down to the client
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps(event['message']))
```

*the result that i have in celery terminal*
 [click to see celery terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLvFr.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, am too facing the same error. How did you get rid of the error??

Comment: Hi, like Aaron said below, I used "group_send" method instead of "send".
async_to_sync ( channel_layer. group_send ) (
        "chat", { "type" : "hello.message" , "message" : "my custom message" }
    )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the channel_layer.send method, but I think you actually want to use channel_layer.group_send instead.